# How to query 1 feature of each category using QGIS (SQL like) expression language?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression

I use QGIS 3.2 to select features in a shapefile. Lets say I have shapefile which contain 100 features and have such fields:

1. `Class` with possible values `A`,`B`,`C`.
2. `ID` with possible integer values `0, 1, 2, 3, ... , 99`.

**How to select exactly one feature (no matter which one) in every class `A`,`B`,`C`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Select by Expression you can type the following expression:

```
"Class" IN ('C', 'B') AND 
"ID" = minimum( "ID", "Class")
```

This expression will select the feature with Class = B, C  with the lowest ID, assuming the ID is a unique value.

If the ID is not a unique value, using the field calculator you can create a new integer column, name it ser_id or something along the line and assign to it the value `$id`. This is the row number and it is a unique value.

[image: field calculator]

Comment: Missing quotes `"` around field name `ID`.

Comment: It can actually work without the double quotes for the field names. If you double-click on the field name from the list on the right, you will get the double quotes, but you can type the field name and it will work equally well. The expression could be `Class = 'A' and ID = minimum(ID)`. This has worked for me.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that.

Comment: That is another question but do you have any ideas how to select `N` features? =)

Comment: If my answer solved your question please accept so people would know it's a valid solution. As for selecting N features, that is indeed another question that requires a bit more of an elaborate code. So better ask a new question as it will get more attention and give a better chance of receiving a proper answer.

Comment: I accept the answer, but it works only if the values of the "ID" field are not repeated. If we got two features with `ID = 1` - two features will be selected.

Comment: Of course, I assume the ID value is unique. If it's not unique, you will get all the features with the minimum ID. A workaround would be to create an additional integer column that gets the row number of the feature and you can select on that. I will edit my answer to account for this possibility.

Comment: While it's often safe to omit `"` double quotes, it's good practice to always use them, so you don't forget it when you suddenly run into a field name with spaces or other fancy characters.

Comment: I test suggested expression and it only work in one situation - when Class's ID value is minimal (zero). Here is the correct expression: `"Class" IN ('B', 'N') AND "ID" = minimum( "ID", "Class")`